# How to push event targets to an object in an array in state with onChange and setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to take an onChange event and push it to an array in state rather than just state. JSX and state below:

```
state = {
  draftboard: []
}
....


{picks.slice(0,2).map((pick) => (
  <Form.Control   
    onChange={this.onChange}
    defaultValue={pick}
    className='mb-2'
    size='sm'
    name='name'
    label={incrementPicks()}
    as="select" >
      {picks.map((pick) => (
        <option>{pick}</option>
      ))}
  </Form.Control>
))}
```

With my onChange being:

```
onChange = (e) => { 
  this.setState(state => {
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }
}
```

Problem is this just sets the state to

```
state: {
    [],
    name: 1
}
```

and what I want is

```
state: {
    [{
       name: 1
    }]  
}
```

How would I set this up properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = ev.target.value;
const name = ev.target.name;
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  draftboard: [
   ...prevState.draftboard,
   { value, name }
  ]
}))
```

Comment: i get cannot read property 'name of null if i do that http://petekehr.com/error.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        draftboard: [
            {
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value]
            },
             ...prevState.draftboard
        ]
    }));
};
```

Comment: @peachcore add ``e.persist();`` in the first line of ``onChange``.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure about what you want, I think this can help you.

```
onChange = e => {        
this.setState(
  {        
  ...this.state,
    draftboard : [
      {
        ...this.state.draftboard[0],
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

}